# Uncaught syntax error unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

(The error is on line 4, I'm sure there are plenty more):

```
   var RPSPlayer = 
   {
   myHistory = new array();
   rivalRock = 0;
   rivalScissors = 0;
   rivalPaper = 0;
   itemChosen;
   victorySum;


  this.choose=function(item)
  {
  myHistory.push(item);
  };

  ...
  {more code here}
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rqMwx/

Comment: You're not declaring the "var" correctly as a native JS object.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: jsFiddle doesn't spit syntax errors :| (I saw your previous comment - thanks a lot!)

Comment: @BoltClock - Firebug does (I always have it open there, so I forget). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well you still need Firebug or another console to see those errors. That was my point ;)

Comment: @BoltClock - I know, that's why I added that note. The fiddle is more useful for those helping (who are more likely to have a console open or ready) than the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there are plenty more. A quick correction:

```
var RPSPlayer = {
   myHistory: [],
   rivalRock: 0,
   rivalScissors: 0,
   rivalPaper: 0,
   choose: function(item) {
       this.myHistory.push(item);
   }
};
```

Comment: wanted to use RPSPlayer as an Object Literal, so 
function is not good? or am i wrong?

Comment: [JavaScript object literals](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/07/javascript-object-literals-a-definition/)

Comment: Well i stil get that annoying error, this time its on the
myHistory = [], and because of the ' = '
any ideas?

Comment: @Itzik984: You need to pay more attention. Also read the link that I just posted.

Comment: i know, having difficulties getting used to the language...ty for the link